Does My OpenGL Device really only support 90 Uniform Buffer Objects?
I am trying to create an OpenGL application that needs a lot of UBO, although a single shader only needs to be able to bind to 6-7 UBO's. And So I was trying to create a bunch of binding points for all my UBO's, but I got an invalid argument error at the 91st UBO when I pass it to glUniformBlockBinding. I saw that GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BINDINGS was at 90, which seems incredibly low to me. Does this really mean my GPU only supports 90s simulatnous UBO's?

There's a lot of confusion in your post. Your mixing Uniform Buffer Objects with Vertex Buffer Objects; binding points count (number of buffers bound at the same time) with object count (number of existing buffers). What is the code that you are actually running and which method exactly fails.

it crashes when I call GL46.glUniformBlockBinding(programID, blockIndex, bindingPoint); with a binding point of 90. Which is according to the specs. To me this looks like my 3060 actually only supports 90 UBO across the entire application

That's 90 UBOs bound to a single shader. Do you really need that much?

I thought the list of binding points applied to the whole application. So you have a global index of binding points that you could bind different shaders to. Because otherwise whats the point of having a seperate block index and binding point index?

Yes, your GPU only supports 90 separate buffers used for uniform data in the same draw call/shader.
You do not bind a buffer permanently to a UBO binding point. Binding to a binding point index is a temporary thing you do only when you want to use that buffer to provide uniform data for a particular shader in a particular draw call. This is no different from a texture; you bind a texture to a texture unit only when you want to use that texture in a rendering operation.
As with textures, you should try to sort your draw operations so that different shaders or draw calls can use the same buffers for uniform data that doesn't change between them (the camera and perspective matrices tend to be the same for many draw calls). But yes, you're expected to bind different buffers as you render the scene.

I thought th block index whas what bound the buffer to the shader. I guess I haven't quite understood what the difference between the block index and the binding point index is then

@user2741831: "I thought th block index whas what bound the buffer to the shader." The UBO binding index (the number you use with glBindBufferRange) is what associates a buffer to the shader that uses it for uniform data. But this association is not permanent. The shader says "I'm looking for a buffer in slot X". You bind a buffer to slot X. When you render, the shader will see the buffer through slot X. The buffer is not bound to the shader.

could you please add an example on how to effectively use uniform block indices and binding point indices to you your answer?

@user2741831: Block indices exist solely for the purpose of introspection. Unless you don't know where a shader is coming from or are trying to conform to some naming convention made by the shader, they're kind of irrelevant. You should just have the shader specify which uniform blocks use which binding indices, and then just bind the appropriate buffers to those indices before you render with those shaders.
